# Printing strings of extremely large size

Tags: python, string, printing, large-data

I am trying to print strings of the length of order 10^16. Doing so with the following code doesn't complete the task. I am struggling to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

```
n=int(input())    # 1<=n<=10^16
s="HelloWorld"
q=(n-1)//10000
r=(n-1)-(q*10000)
print(s,end="")
for i in range(q):
    print("s"*10000,end="")
print("s"*r)
```

Here I am trying to print the string consisting of "s" in chunks of 10000 but still, this doesn't work. My system crashes upon executing this.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you really need to print the string? what for if I may ask? I'm sure you could not possible inspect the input by reading...

Comment: What is the objective of such a task?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I wanted to see that is that any fast way of printing extremely large strings or do I need to do it like this and wait till my system crashes.

Comment: if you have a 32 bit machine, the limit of printing strings is `2^32 - 1 (= 4294967296 < 10^16)`, so this is one reason.

Comment: I am not sure of the point of printing a large text in the first place. If you are using print for writing text to a file, then use a generator. ;) A function that will yield the text without writing to memory

Comment: If you only want to crash your system, there are easier ways of doing that. If not, try not to do it. What do you want to do with the output? maybe there are ways to do it without crashing your system.

Comment: A string whose length is on the order of 10^16 would require on the order of 10 *petabytes* of  memory. You can't generate that `str` object in the first place, never mind print it quickly.

Comment: BTW, `q, r = divmod(n, 10000)`.

Comment: Also, is your system actually *crashing*, or is it just taking a long time to print a trillion lines?